# Can I change XmlReader.Settings?

Tags: c#, xml

I am a library which has a method which parses XML from the supplied XmlReader. So, the caller passes me XmlReader instance (or an instance of any derived class) but I need to make sure whitespaces are ignored. I.e. I want to do this:

```
xmlReader.Settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
// Then do my parsing
// Finally, revert to whatever state xmlReader.Settings had prior to calling my method
```

However, if the caller didn't instantiate XmlReaderSettings when creating XmlReader instance, I don't see the way how I can fix this myself.

For instance, if the caller used this code:

```
XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(File.OpenRead("file.xml"));
```

reader.Settings will remain null. This property is read-only so I can't assign it.

I'm not responsible for the caller and I don't force them to use this or that way of getting XmlReader instance and configuring it. I know XmlTextReader is deprecated but it's still available in .NET 4.6 and folks can use it.

Does this mean there is no way to work around this in my library and it's the caller who must supply me already well-configured XmlReader?

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the provided `XmlReader` into a new one using [`XmlReader.Create()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1h1125x(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public void ReadMyXml(XmlReader reader)
{
    XmlReaderSettings settings = reader.Settings ?? new XmlReaderSettings();
    settings.IgnoreWhitespace = true;
    settings.CloseInput = false;
    using(XmlReader myReader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings))
    {
        // use myReader to read the xml
    }
}
```

Set `settings.CloseInput = false` if you want to avoid closing the original reader at the end (thanks to Jon Hanna for the comment)

Comment: `settings.CloseInput` should control that last aspect.

Comment: Thanks. However, in my tests `settings.CloseInput = false` doesn't have any effect. The reader.ReadState changes to Closed immediately after 'using' scope ends.

Comment: Looks like settings.CloseInput only makes sense when XmlReader is created from Stream or TextReader, not from another XmlReader.

Comment: @Alex sorry for that. I'll keep researching. I think this is called decorator pattern and according to the pattern the wrapping class takes responsibility. I wonder why `CloseInput` does not have an effect on the other classes...